# Changing date and time between timezones

Tags: php

I have been trying to convert between timezones a given date and time.

Code speaks more than words, so here it is:

```
/**
 * Returns the date and time in the new timezone.
 *
 * @param string $datetime:
 *          the date and time to change between timezones
 * @param string $input_tz:
 *          the input timezone
 * @param string $output_tz:
 *          the output timezone
 * @return string The new date and time
 */
public function changeDateTime($datetime, $input_tz, $output_tz) {
    if($input_tz == $output_tz) return $datetime;
    /*
     * We calculate the hour and minute offset from GMT
     */
    date_default_timezone_set($output_tz);
    $out_dst = date('I', $datetime) ? 1 : 0;
    $out_hour_offset = intval(substr(date('O', $datetime), 1, 3)) + $out_dst;
    $out_minute_offset = intval(substr(date('O', $datetime)), - 2);

    date_default_timezone_set($input_tz);
    $in_dst = date('I', $datetime) ? 1 : 0;
    $in_hour_offset = intval(substr(date('O', $datetime), 1, 3)) + $in_dst;
    $in_minute_offset = intval(substr(date('O', $datetime)), - 2);

    /*
     * We subtract hour and minute offsets to come up with total difference
     */
    $hour_offset = $out_hour_offset - $in_hour_offset;
    $minute_offset = $out_minute_offset - $in_minute_offset;

    /*
     * Now we must take care of changing the day/month/year if necessary, as
     * well as the hour/minute for $datetime, and return that value.
     */
    $date = new DateTime($datetime);
    if($hour_offset > 0) {
        $date->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string($hour_offset . ' hours'));
        if($minute_offset > 0) $date->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string($minute_offset . ' minutes'));
    } else if($hour_offset < 0) {
        $date->sub(date_interval_create_from_date_string($hour_offset . ' hours'));
        if($minute_offset > 0) $date->sub(date_interval_create_from_date_string($minute_offset . ' minutes'));
    }
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

However, it does not seem to work well. This is the code I am running to test whether it works or not:

```
$newdatetime = $gato->changeDateTime("2012-08-10 11:33:33", 'Europe/London', 'Europe/Madrid');
echo $newdatetime;
```

And this is my expected output: 2012-08-10 12:33:33
But this is my actual output: 2012-08-10 11:33:33, which means there is no change in time.

Comment: From where I see it, there is a 1 hour change

Comment: Hmm then you probably need some glasses ^^

Comment: Why make this so complicated? Just store date/time as UTC. That will not change wherever you are on this planet. Then change the UTC to the appropriate time zone.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not in control of the server where this is ran, and the times are stored in current UK Time (ie. it might or it might not have DST on).

Comment: @jslvtr Am I missing something, or are you passing a string to a function that's expecting an integer?

Comment: @DaveRandom, could you specify? Which function do you mean?

Comment: @jslvtr Well you seem to be passing a string into your function (`2012-08-10 11:33:33`) and then passing it directly as the second argument to `date()`, which would be expecting a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: That is true... I shall convert to UNIX timestamp before, and then I won't need to work with the input timezone, only the output one.

Comment: @jslvtr Now i've actually started to pull the code apart I've found a number of things that make no sense - give me 5 mins I'll come back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, try this instead:

```
function changeDateTime($datetime, $input_tz, $output_tz) {

    // Return original string if in and out are the same
    if($input_tz == $output_tz) {
        return $datetime;
    }

    // Save current timezone setting and set to input timezone
    $original_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
    date_default_timezone_set($input_tz);

    // Get Unix timestamp based on input time zone
    $time = strtotime($datetime);

    // Start working in output timezone
    date_default_timezone_set($output_tz);

    // Calculate result
    $result = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);

    // Set timezone correct again
    date_default_timezone_set($original_tz);

    // Return result
    return $result;

}

$out = changeDateTime("2012-08-10 11:33:33", 'Europe/London', 'Europe/Madrid');
var_dump($out);
```

Rather than messing about doing all that complicated maths, just let PHP do all the hard work for you ;-)

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wb06JO)

Comment: That is great! Thank you very much for the effort and time there. :)
Do I have to return to the original timezone always?

Comment: @jslvtr You don't *have* to return to the original timezone, but I think it makes sense to do so. Say your server is in the UK, and someone asks you to convert a time from somewhere in the US to somewhere in Japan, if you *don't* go back to the default timezone then for the rest its execution your script will think it is in Japan, which could cause problems.

Comment: I see... Usually the script that I'm running that uses this function wouldn't mind, since it processes one datetime change per call, but it does make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your stumbling on this, it can be done cleaner now with the DateTime Object.

```php
public function convertTZ($dateTimeString, $inputTZ, $outputTZ){
    $datetime = 
        \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', //input format - iso8601
        $dateTimeString, 
        new \DateTimeZone($inputTZ))
        ->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('$outputTZ'));

    //outputs a string, if you want the dateTime obj - remove ->format
    return $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //output format 

}
```