# Convert timestamp to datetime with different timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I want to convert timestamp to datetime string, but not using server timezone like

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $timestamp);
```

because date will use server timezone to make datestring. I want to use `$timezone` as param for converting.

Comment: Is `$timestamp` a Unix Timestamp?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20288830/2512304

Comment: you can't. date() doesn't accept any timezone options. you'd have to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) instead.

Comment: @JohnConde Yes, it is unixt timestamp

Comment: @MarcB DateTime() uses datetime string as param, and I have to change timestamp to datetime string, and that is the problem I have in the beggining. I know date() don't take timezone as param, and that is why I want to make function which will have to timezone param

Comment: yes, but there's date_create_from_format so you can feed in a time string AND timezone.

Comment: @MarcB yeah, you're right :) I'll make answer to this question with   php function. Tnx