# php - Parse.com change createdAt Column timezone

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm developing a PHP project and I'm using Parse SDK. What i want to do is adjust the time given by the Parse Database. It gives me time and date that 8 hours late to my timezone. Here's the code I'm using :

```
$query = new ParseQuery("TestObject");
$query->get("xWMyZ4YEGZ");
$dateTime = $query->getCreatedAt();
$sched = $dateTime->format("M d, Y - hA");
echo $sched;
```

How can i adjust it to specifically "GMT+8" TimeZone? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `date_default_timezone_set` before doing any thing as:

```
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) 
          date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
```

[List of timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) are provided here...

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I tried `if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) 
          date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GTM+8");`

Comment: have you put the line before new ParseQuery

Comment: Yup, i put it on the very top below `<?php` line

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PHP date with TZ - See N.B.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288789/php-date-with-timezone) here is a code snippet he suggests (you may be able to use the parse date instead of the "now" parameter):

```
<?php
$tz = 'Europe/London';
$timestamp = time();
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz)); //first argument "must" be a string
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp
echo $dt->format('d.m.Y, H:i:s');
```