# Date Time Function PHP

Tags: php

This Screenshot Date Time My Laptop..

[image]

This Screenshot My Script Result

[image]

This My Syntax

```
<?php
session_start();
$time = date('Y-m-d, H:i:s');
echo $time;
?>
```

Why not same..
Please Help Me..
Sorry My English Language Is Bad And I'm Newbie

Comment: because you didn't set Time Zone...

Comment: How To Set it ?

Comment: You're asking about the time or the format?

Comment: i'm Asking about date and time, because my database have 1 field date time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288789/php-date-with-timezone

Comment: you can try to set default timezone via `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is something you need to see ....

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.settimezone.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.1 returns the time of the SERVER, which can be anywhere in the world.

Your computer displays your LOCAL time (or whichever time zone you set it up as, typically your local time zone).

Use Milos' solution to tell PHP what timezone you want to use. But many people will recommend using a timeserver for 100% accuracy, as your Server (as well as your computer) may not be set correctly itself.

See http://www.kloth.net/software/timesrv1.php for timeserver examples.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 <?php

 $date_time = new DateTime();
 echo $date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 ?>
```