# Java timestamp to php timestamp

Tags: java, php, date, timestamp

I want to convert a Java timestamp into a php timestamp. I have a java code that creates a JSON Object and send the content of this object to a php-page, which should store them into a database.

My problem is, that the timestamps are different.

Java:

```
Wed Dec 14 14:06:07 CET 2016
```

The output (as long converted):

```
1481720767015
```

On php I tried two different solutions:

PHP:

```
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s', intval("1481720767015")/1000);
echo "<br>".gmdate('d.m.Y H:i:s', intval("1481720767015")/1000);
```

The output:

```
14.12.2016 08:06:07
14.12.2016 13:06:07
```

So how can I change the timezone to get the second output to the right time/timezone?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar problem here : [PHP date(); with timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288789/php-date-with-timezone#answer-20289096)

And the solution is - you need to pass the timezone when creating the date object like below :

```
$tz = 'Europe/London';
$timestamp = time();
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz)); //first argument "must" be a string
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp
echo $dt->format('d.m.Y, H:i:s');
```

Comment: thank you. I found another solution:

    $time = gmdate('d.m.Y H:i:s', intval("1481720767015")/1000);
    $time = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($time)+60*60);

Comment: Your example does not use any timezon but directly use some raw interval ;)

Answer (score 0):

thank you. I found another solution:

```
$time = gmdate('d.m.Y H:i:s', intval("1481720767015")/1000);
$time = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($time)+60*60);
```