# Server time not same to local time

Tags: php

I am from Bangladesh.I am not getting the right time from this code ?

```
 <html>
      <head>  
        <title>Server time</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>The time at the server is 
        <?php 
        print date('h:i:s A');
        ?>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Output is:

```
The time at the server is 08:58:51 PM
```

But actual time is then `01:58:51 AM`

Comment: always use date_default_timezone_set(); for correct time zone. check below link for supported timezones http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: See also [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date(); with timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288789/php-date-with-timezone)

Comment: if you use your server for use in your own country, you might wanna move it for faster response as well :) looks like the server is on another continent :P

Comment: Probably your os webserver time is not set up properly.

Comment: How to set web server time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) function for correct time in your script
In your case use like this

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
    echo date_default_timezone_get();
?>
```

Comment: The time at the server is Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.

Comment: Then open your php.ini file with the File Manager in cPanel and set your desired time as well