# date_default_timezone_set() is being applied the same for everyone

Tags: php

I want to set the timezone to the visitor's timezone.

I am doing it like this way:

```
$ip = $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the IP address to query
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
  date_default_timezone_set($query['timezone']);
} else {
  echo 'Unable to get location';
}
```

However, when another visitor visits the site he will have the timezone of the previous visitor ...

Why doesn't `date_default_timezone` clears? Is there's any solution to that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_REQUEST` is used to get data from GET/POST request. It should be `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Code

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the IP address to query
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
  date_default_timezone_set($query['timezone']);
  echo 'timezone set to '.$query['timezone'];
} else {
  echo 'Unable to get location';
}
```

Output

```
timezone set to Asia/Kolkata
```

Explanation:

`$_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']` have no value, mean `$ip` is empty. If you query `http://ip-api.com/php/` without ip, it'll get request ip by default and shows that request data not ip data. That's why you're getting same timezone for every visitors.

**Bonus**

You can get visitors timezone without using any API. `$_SERVER['COOKIE']` have `timezone` of visitors.

snippet

```
parse_str($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'], $cookie);
if(isset($cookie['timezone'])){
   date_default_timezone_set($cookie['timezone']);
}
else{
   echo 'Unable to get location'; //or do something!
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the bonus too! I didn't know that the `HTTP_COOKIE` header would contain such value.

Comment: You're welcome! If you want more information like visitor's user-agent etc... you can `print_r($_SERVER);` 
`Happy Coding`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer of "Smartpal" is very good but I still have the same problem with it.

So I've heard that `date_default_timezone_set()` is outdated and old - That's why I've switched to the `DateTime()` class.

and now instead of using `date('G')` I can do it like that:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the IP address to query
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
$tz = $query['timezone'];
$timestamp = time();
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz));
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
echo $dt->format('G');
```

This worked fine for me.

Source of the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20289096/8524395