# php 5 and php 8 date convert result is different

Tags: php

```
$opening_date = '2020-01-01T00:00:00+08:00'         
$opening_date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($opening_date));
```

PHP 5.6 result

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

PHP 8.0 result

```
2019-12-31 00:00:00
```

Hi, I'm doing date converting with different version but have no idea why the code is same but result is different. The expected result shall be `2020-01-01 00:00:00` but in PHP8.0 it minus 1 day. Is there any solution about this?

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://3v4l.org/BJJV2) your error, is this all the code? can you make sure the timezone setting are the same on both version.

Comment: date function vs DateTime object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288789/php-date-with-timezone/20289096

Answer (score 0):

This is not the issue related to version of PHP. I think you have not defined the timezone correctly.

This is the code that I have written. (Assuming New_York as timezone)

```
<?php
$timezone = "America/New_York";
$opening_date = '2020-01-01T00:00:00+08:00';
echo $opening_date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($opening_date));
?>
```

& in both versions of PHP, It is showing me the same output.

**PHP Version: 8.0.0**
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66fd1dd83dafbc1749383990effbb8586c922c15

**PHP Version: 5.6.2**
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66fd1dd83dafbc1749383990effbb8586c922c15