# How to convert T-Z string to australian time?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I have a string time `2020-05-18T15:58:01Z`. How can I convert it into `Australia/Sydney` time in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s` so that its a date or datetime object?

```
$str = '2020-05-18T15:58:01Z';
$converted = strtotime($str);
echo(converted)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP date() with timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288789/php-date-with-timezone)

Comment: @catcon Not really, how would I pass in `$str`

Comment: You can create a `DateTime` object with your `$str`, then change that object timezone to `Australia/Sydney`, see [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9f9892ed91d9dab2e0afaefc96f92cd5e112d9b)