# php date() returns one hour ahead of original when given integer date

Tags: php, mysql, date

The php `date()` function is returning a strange result. For example:

```
date("d/m/Y H:i",$sr1["parking_start"]);
```

Here the `$sr1["parking_start"]` is the date in integer format retrieved from the database. It should return the result `2016/4/24 15:30`, but it returns `2016/4/24 16:30` or `2016/4/24 14:30`. I have tried my best to sort it out but in vain. If you people think this is a server time issue then let me tell you that it's not, because when I copy and paste the value of `$sr1["parking_start"]` and paste it to the date function of the other php file on the same server, then its works perfectly.

Can you help me? What can cause the `date()` function to return the wrong result?

Comment: Convert your dates in PHP and ship them in as a normalized value. Ideally you use UTC for everything on the server so as to avoid time zone issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your default timezone [date_default_timezone_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) (and make sure you set it correctly).
You might want to check what was the timezone of the script that saved the date and, if different, you will have to [change between the zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900126/changing-date-and-time-between-timezones)